# PHP and MATLAB base64_decode works differently

Tags: php, matlab, base64, decode

I am trying to write a base64 decode function in MATLAB.
In PHP, if I call built-in base64 decode function

```
$decodedStr = base64_decode($encodedStr)
```

`$decodedStr` is the result I want.

Now, I need to pass `$encodedStr` from PHP to MATLAB (as a parameter), and in MATLAB, I decode the string, same as PHP code above.

```
function base64_decode_matlab(x)
    %x is same value as $encodedStr
    base64 = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
    decodedStr1 = base64.decode(uint8(x));
end
```

However, it seems like the result is different than the result from PHP. What's wrong with my MATLAB code and how can I make the MATLAB base64 decode function works same as the PHP `base64_decode` function?

Comment: What's the original string and what does the decoded string from matlab equal?

Comment: I just checked both MATLAB and php. They both produce same encoded and decoded strings for same input.

Comment: @Navan Do you mean the MATLAB code above produces the same decoded string as base64_decode in PHP? Thanks

Comment: I tried the php code <?php
$x = "abcdefghij";
echo "$x\n";
$encodedStr = base64_encode($x);
echo "$encodedStr\n";
$decodedStr = base64_decode($encodedStr);
echo "\n$decodedStr";
?> and MATLAB code x = 'abcdefghij';  enc = base64.encode(uint8(x));  dec = base64.decode(enc). All strings matched between php and MATLAB at each step.

Comment: Note that decoderStr1 from MATLAB is of type int8. You need to cast it to char type.